# Grails render template by remote action

Tags: grails

I'm trying to update a view partially by a remote action

This is my view (`home/index.gsp`)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
<g:render template="datetime", model="[mybean: mybean]"/>
```

This is my template (home/_datetime.gsp)

```
<p>Time: ${mybean.getHours()} : ${mybean.getMinutes()} : ${mybean.getSeconds()}</p>
```

This is my js

```
$("button.btn-success").click(function(event){
    $.post("/home/updateTime")
})
```

This is my controller

```
class HomeController {

    def index() {
        def bean = new MyDateBean()
        render view:"index", model:[mybean:bean]
    }

    def updateTime(){
        log.debug("Updating time")
        def bean = new MyDateBean()
        render template:"datetime", model:[mybean:bean]
    }


    class MyDateBean{

        private String hours
        private String minutes
        private String seconds

        MyDateBean(){
            def date = new Date()
            this.hours = date.format("H")
            this.minutes = date.format("m")
            this.seconds = date.format("s")
        }

        String getHours(){
            return this.hours
        }

        String getMinutes(){
            return this.minutes
        }

        String getSeconds(){
            return this.seconds
        }
    }   
}
```

If I browse to `/home/index` the template is rendered correctly, but when I click the button the template does not update. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the template in a div e.g.

```
<div id="dtsDiv">
    <g:render template="datetime" model="[mybean: mybean]"/>
</div>
```

Then use the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready( function() {

        $("button.btn-success").click(function(event){
            $.ajax({
                url: "${g.createLink( controller:'test', action:'updateTime')}",
                type: 'get'
            }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#dtsDiv' ).html( data ); });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what you have written works but does not use render template grails feature

Comment: When your page (index.gsp) is loaded, all tags, and expressions are evaluated. You can't trigger a re-render without reloading the page. In this case homeController/updateTime causes the re-render, returns the result, and is set to the DOM via jQuery.

Comment: change above to `.success( function ( data) {
                $( '#dtsDiv' ).html( data);
            });`  this will render the actual data aka your template back over div this is javascript basics dude

Answer (score 0):

I think comment above answers your concerns of rendering template. Comments point out that when you trigger a jquery method (ajax) call a request is made to controller and can be captured with

```
if (request.xhr) {
 render template:'template'
 return
}
// since we return above no need for else and so hence otherwise
render view: 'view'
```

When an ajax request is made to controller only a template can be returned so your own comment is kind of actually wrong besides that Mike has suggested rendering response text.

Anyhow reason for my answer was unrelated to actual question more related to ease of groovy vs java methods

try

```
<p>Time: ${mybean.hours} : ${mybean.minutes} : ${mybean.seconds}</p>
```

try

class HomeController {

```
def index(MyDateBean bean) {
    render view:"index", model:[mybean:bean]
}

def updateTime(MyDateBean bean){
    log.debug("Updating time")
    render template:"datetime", model:[mybean:bean]
}


class MyDateBean{

    def date=new Date()

    String getHours(){
        return  date.format("H")
    }

    String getMinutes(){
        return  date.format("m")
    }

    String getSeconds(){
        return  date.format("s")
    }
}   
}
```